# Why MKiCloudSync doesn't sync NSUserDefaults?

Tags: objective-c, synchronization, nsuserdefaults, icloud, mkicloudsync

I imported the MKiCloudSync files and it has been working fine for months.
Now, I don't know why, it doesn't sync NSUserDefaults across devices with same iCloud account enabled.
If i run the application on different devices of the simulator it works fine.

Where am I wrong? Because it worked fine until now; I also checked my iCloud storage and I have got 4.3 Gb out of 5.

Let's say I've got 4 empty strings out of 10 saved on iCloud
If I delete the app from my iPhone and reinstall it I'll get them back but of I set other strings (ie 2 empty strings left out of 10), delete the app and reinstall it, I'll get the 6 strings and 4 empty.

It seems MKiCloudSync can only download NSUserDefaults and can't upload the edited ones.

Any ideas? 
Thanks really much.

Simone.

Comment: You have the source code to MKiCloudSync; have you made any attempt to debug the problem? If so, what were the results?

Comment: No I hadn't the time to do that. Today I'll try and will let you know. Thanks